# AWS Elastic Container Service CI Template issue

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs

I’m on gitlab.com and tried deploying to a fargate AWS ECS container using the instructions for including the Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci.yml template found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#deploy-your-application-to-aws-elastic-container-service-ecs).

It is failing with the following error:

```
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
$ ecs update-task-definition
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE.
Running after_script
00:01
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I believe I may have found a solution [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3983) where Ryangr() advises that the `--requires-compatibilities "FARGATE"` flag needs to be on added to the `aws ecs register-task-definition` command. This is supported by the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html)

```
In the AWS Management Console, for the Requires Compatibilities field, specify FARGATE.
In the AWS CLI, specify the --requires-compatibilities option.
In the Amazon ECS API, specify the requiresCompatibilities flag.
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to override the Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci.yml template and add that or if I just need to submit an issue ticket with GitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again with [GitLab 13.2 (July 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/07/22/gitlab-13-2-released/#manage-php-dependencies-with-the-gitlab-composer-repository):

> ### Bring Fargate support for ECS to Auto DevOps and ECS template

> We want to make AWS deployments easier.
> In order to do so, we recently delivered a CI/CD template that deploys to AWS ECS:EC2 targets and even connected it to Auto DevOps.
>
> Scaling container instances in EC2 is a challenge, so many users choose to use AWS Fargate instead of EC2 instances.
> **In this release we added Fargate support to the template, which continues to work with Auto DevOps as well, so more users can benefit from it.**

This is linked to [issue 218841](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218841) which includes the proposal:

> Use the `gitlab-ci.yml` template for deploying to AWS Fargate.
>
> We will enforce the presence of `--requires-compatibilities` argument from the launch type - this will only be passed in case Fargate is selected.
> If ECS is selected as the launch type this is ignored.

As noted by the [David Specht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355006/david-specht) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994312/aws-elastic-container-service-ci-template-issue/63094687#comment111653578_63094687), this has been closed with [issue 218798](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218798) and [cloud-deploy MR (Merge Request) 16](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/-/merge_requests/16), in [commit 2c3d198](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/-/commit/2c3d198ecf5e3d25f86de20a17b9d7ee23afbce6).

Comment: It appears they fixed it with this closed issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218798

Comment: @DavidSpecht Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with some additional links/references.